# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known after Python Paramiko Upgrade

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, ssh, paramiko

I recently updated Python Paramiko on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS to resolve an issue with SSH compatibility. The error I had been receiving was:
paramiko.SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm) The research on this error concluded that there is an incompatibility issue with OpenSSH 6.7 and Paramiko with a version less than 1.15.1, so I upgraded to Version 1.15.1. This resolved my SSH connection issue, but seems to have broken my SMTP Email routine which had previously been working. The Email syntax is as follows:

```
from email.MIMEText      import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase      import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart

smtpserver   = 'server.company.com'
AUTHREQUIRED = 0
smtpuser     = ''
smtppass     = ''
RECIPIENTS   = ['person@company.com']
SENDER       = ['person@company.com']

session = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)    
if AUTHREQUIRED:
    session.login(smtpuser, smtppass)
smtpresult = session.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENTS, results.as_string()) 
if smtpresult:
    errstr = ""
    for recip in smtpresult.keys():
        errstr = """Could not deliver mail to: %s    
Server said: %s
%s    
%s"""   (recip, smtpresult[recip][0], smtpresult[recip][1], errstr)
        raise smtplib.SMTPException, errstr
```

This is the traceback I get with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 179, in <module>
    session = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I am having difficulty determining what needs to be corrected in order to restore the Email capability to my script. Has anyone faced a similar situation, and if so, how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out that the admin on the Ubuntu server was correcting an issue with the server not being able to reach a time server. The DNS was changed, and the new DNS did not have a registration for the mail server I am using. Once the DNS was changed back, the Email worked again.